# Output a "advanced-custom-fields"-field programmatically in wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field with the "advanced-custom-fields"-plugin.  Now I want to get and output the custom field programmatically in my template file (backend, edit page), because my template is called via ajax if user want's to add a new region to the page.

Is there any function which returns the complete field? I only found functions which gave me values, but not the field as "form".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I duplicated the plugin folder into my theme root directory and put the following code into my functions.php:

```
function relationshipField() {
    $newField       = new acf_field_relationship();
    $field          = array(
                         'post_type'       =>   array('post'),
                         'max'             =>   '',
                         'taxonomy'        =>   array('all'),
                         'filters'         =>   array('search'),
                         'result_elements' =>   array('post_title', 'post_type'),
                         'return_format'   =>   'object'
                     );

    return $newField->create_field($field);
}
```

In addition I append a custom input field (created in function.php) which stores only the post id's in database.